# How can I move my iPod music to an iPad?

Tags: music, ipod, data-transfer

How can I get the songs out of my iPod and move them to an iPad?

I thought I could just copy the music to my computer and then transfer it to the iPad, but didn't work (I couldn't see any music file on my iPod). Any other methods?

Comment: iPod --> iTunes ---> iPad

Comment: What kind of ipod?

Comment: Can we presume you have an iPod that isn't an iPod touch, that you want playlists transferred and you didn't buy the songs from iTunes store?

Comment: Are you using Mac or PC?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out: [How-to: get music, videos, and photos off your iPod or iPhone](http://www.engadget.com/2009/11/25/how-to-get-music-videos-and-photos-off-your-ipod-iphone/).

After you get the music off of your ipod and into your computer/itunes you can just sync it normally to your ipad, or any other idevice for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please make sure that iTunes is set to *manually manage music*. Then follow these steps:

1. Connect iPod to computer, go to *My Computer*, double click iPod drive, choose `Tools` > `Folder Options` > `View`, then select `Show Hidden Files & Folders` and click “OK”
2. Right click **iPod Control** folder, select **Properties**, deselect **Hidden** and click “OK”. Then select `Apply Changes To This Folder, Subfolder And Files` and click “OK” .
3. Click **iPod Control** folder and open **Music** , did you see folders labeled F00, F01, F02, F03…? Now Place iTunes side by side with this window, and make sure that **Music Library** is displayed.
4. In iTunes select `Edit` > `Preferences` > `Advanced`, and check: **Keep iTunes Music Folder Organized** and **Copy Files To iTunes Music Folder When Adding To Library**, then click “OK”.
5. Drag and drop all of the above “F…” folders into **Music Library** of iTunes.

This might be a little complicated, but it definitely works well, and it’s totally free. Some aspects may not apply to Mac users.

Answer (score 0):

Try synchronising your iPod to your computer through iTunes and then synchronising your iPad to iTunes on the same computer.

Music files on the iPod are usually seen as jargon and you cannot usually tell which song is which. It is a safer bet to sync using iTunes.